# After pgr_createTopology, how should I use pgr_dijkstra?

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2pgsql, dijkstra

Using the OpenStreetMap data and `osm2pgsql`, I created a topology by using the `pgr_createTopology()` function. These tables are what I have:

```
                          List of relations
 Schema |                 Name                 |   Type   |  Owner   
--------+--------------------------------------+----------+----------
 public | geography_columns                    | view     | postgres
 public | geometry_columns                     | view     | postgres
 public | planet_osm_line                      | table    | postgres
 public | planet_osm_nodes                     | table    | postgres
 public | planet_osm_point                     | table    | postgres
 public | planet_osm_polygon                   | table    | postgres
 public | planet_osm_rels                      | table    | postgres
 public | planet_osm_roads                     | table    | postgres
 public | planet_osm_roads_vertices_pgr        | table    | postgres
 public | planet_osm_roads_vertices_pgr_id_seq | sequence | postgres
 public | planet_osm_ways                      | table    | postgres
 public | spatial_ref_sys                      | table    | postgres
(12 rows)
```

Now I want to run `pgr_dijkstra()` to find the shortest path.

Which table and columns should I use? Which column represents start_vid and end_vid?

Answer (score 2):

Like explain in the [documentation](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_dijkstra.html) the `pgr_dijkstra` function need the following parameters :

1. `Edges SQL` : A string that represents a SQL query for extract the *edges* from your *edge_table*.
2. `start_vid` : An integer or an array of integers corresponding to the id (in the *vertices tables* ) of the start point(s).
3. `end_vid`: An integer or an array of integers corresponding to the id (in the *vertices tables* ) of the end point(s).
4. (optional) `directed` : A boolean which indicates if the graph is directed (in this case you need a *reverse_cost* column in your *edge_table*.

If your *edge_table* has the default names the query will look like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM edge_table',
    2, 
    3,
    FALSE
);
```

*NB:* For the query to work, a positive cost must be assigned to each section (the function `pgr_createTopology` does not), for example with the following query :

```
UPDATE edge_table SET cost = St_length(geom);
```

Comment: Thanks. What should be my `edge_table`? Would it be `planet_osm_roads`? I tried `select osm_id as id, source, target from planet_osm_roads;` but where can I find `geom` or `cost`?

Comment: `select * from pgr_dijkstra(
'select osm_id as id, source, target, St_length(way) as cost from planet_osm_roads', 10325, 10320, False);`

I tried this and it worked! Thanks a lot!!